# Unable to build android with ionic.

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am currently unable to build my android app using ionic.

Whenever I run `ionic build android`, I get an `Unexpected Error ]` response.

I've looked everywhere from `build.gradle` to `android.json` and have not found any unmatched `]`.

Anyone have any advice/input/experience? Thanks so much!

Comment: It would be more useful if you can post your code and/or the relevant part if you are looking for specific advise for debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a trailing comma in `android.json` after a `}`. 
This was the reason the build was failing.